# Sum a generated list in MySQL, in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I need to sum a result that I'm getting from an existing query. And the it has to extend the current query and remain a single query

(by this I mean NOT - DO 1; DO 2; DO3;)

My current query is:

```
SELECT SUM((count)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mobile_site_statistics WHERE campaign_id='1201' AND start_time BETWEEN CURDATE()-1 AND CURDATE())*100) AS percentage FROM mobile_site_statistics WHERE device NOT LIKE '%Pingdom%' AND campaign_id='1201' AND start_time BETWEEN (CURDATE()-1) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY device ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This returns:

```
+------------+
| percentage |
+------------+
|    47.3813 |
|    19.7940 |
|     5.6672 |
|     5.0801 |
|     3.9603 |
|     3.8500 |
|     3.1294 |
|     2.9924 |
|     2.9398 |
|     2.7136 |
+------------+
```

What I need is the total of that table (total percent used by the top 10 devices)(that's all) but it has to be a single query (Has to include the initial query)(Has to be a single query due to another program that's using the query)

Is this possible? every way I have tried so far has failed. We tried temporary tables, but that turned into multiple queries.

Comment: Just do a `SELECT SUM(percentage) AS total FROM (<YOUR_QUERY>) a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a

```
SELECT SUM(percentage) AS total FROM (<YOUR_QUERY>) a
```

and replace the sub-query `<YOUR_QUERY>` with your initial query